# Class 'PhpParser\Parser\Php7' not found Laravel when using Mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I had no problems since a week ago, now when I try to send a Mail via : `Mail::queue('myemail', $data, function($message)  use ($data){....});`

I have the following error :

```
FatalErrorException in ParserFactory.php line 27:
Class 'PhpParser\Parser\Php7' not found
```

what can I do to solve this issue ? I'm using wampserver 3.0.4 and laravel 5.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/issues/291 it worked to me,  drop the "nikic/php-parser" directory in vendor/ and running composer update.

Comment: I think this worked for me before, but when I was moving a Laravel installation to production recently it didn't work. `vendor/nikic/php-parser` directory was there, but when I tried running `php artisan tinker` it still gave the same error message. I deleted the `vendor/nikic` directory, then ran `composer update` again. It worked after that.